# collective effort in answering bounty question

Tags: feature-request, bounty

This is to know whether I can give all who helped me get the answer their due. As I see, there is provision only to award the bounty to one answer. Is there a way to award multiple answers?

Comment: [One answer per bounty, them's the rules.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/152819)

Comment: So that justice is served, the bounty on your question should be awarded to [Karl Weierstrass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karl_Weierstrass).

Comment: @Rahul: that could be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[One answer per bounty, them's the rules.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2786/152819)

To quote:

> The goal isn't to have multiple answers each containing a piece of the puzzle. It's to have a single, correct, comprehensive answer. Bounty provides a means of encouraging answers to tough problems by offering a reward: allowing you to subdivide this reward creates a situation where you're misleading those participating (who think they're competing for a big prize but only receive a portion of it) and potentially discouraging users from taking the time to write a complete answer.